# How do I get a phone number from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

private func showCreateProfileVC() {

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let dvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateProfileVC") as! CreateProfileVC

    dvc.currentUser = Firebase.Auth // there's an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Auth.Type' to type 'User'"

    self.present(dvc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: could you clarify the question a bit more?
explain what are you trying to achieve and what have you tried already

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code here

```
// there's an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Auth.Type' to type 'User'"
dvc.currentUser = Firebase.Auth
```

because you need to access the currentUser property of Firebase auth.

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
   //do something with the user object
   dvc.currentUser = user

   //to get the current users uid
   let uid = user.uid
}
```

Assume you are using the Real Time Database and have your users stored like this

```
users
   uid_0
      phone_number: "111-222-3333"
```

and you want to retrieve the user with uid_0 phone number. Here's the code

```
func getUsersPhoneNumber() {
    let uid = //the current users uid from above
    self.ref.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        let phone = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "phone_number").value as? String ?? "No Number"
        print(phone)
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
111-222-3333
```